# Intellij analysis not picking up unmanagedSourceDirectories after sbt import

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

If I define an sbt scala project that depends on two external source folders the analysis does not work correctly. So say I define the following build.sbt:

```
lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "repro",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile +=
            baseDirectory.value / ".." / "ext1" /  "src" / "main" / "scala",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile +=
      baseDirectory.value / ".." / "ext2" /  "src" / "main" / "scala"
  )
```

such that sources in ext1 depend on sources in ext2. So in this example I've defined a trati T1 in ext1 and a trait T2 in ext2 that depends on T1. And I have a class in my project that depends on T2. This will all compile fine in sbt. But when I import this sbt project in IntelliJ it compiles. However, when I open my trait T2 in the editor it gives me an error when I reference T1, saying "Cannot resolve ext1". Why am I getting this error?

The reproduction of this issue can be found on github with the following links:

https://github.com/hughgearse/repro

https://github.com/hughgearse/ext1

https://github.com/hughgearse/ext2

Answer (score 0):

Create build definition in `ext1/build.sbt`

```
lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "ext1",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
  )
```

and then reference `ext1` as an external build in `ext2/build.sbt` via [`RootProject`](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration#project-references)

```
val ext1 = RootProject( file("../ext1") )

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(ext1)
  .settings(
    name := "ext2",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
  )
```

and then similarly reference both as external builds in `repro/build.sbt`

```
val ext1 = RootProject( file("../ext1") )
val ext2 = RootProject( file("../ext2") )

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(ext1, ext2)
  .settings(
    name := "repro",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile +=
            baseDirectory.value / ".." / "ext1" /  "src" / "main" / "scala",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile +=
      baseDirectory.value / ".." / "ext2" /  "src" / "main" / "scala"
  )
```

Re-import `repro` project and IntelliJ should be able to analyse all the sources.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as in my real live example ext1 and ext2 are actually full projects also. They use scala 2.12 and my repro scala 2.11 (which cannot be changed). So when I use dependsOn I get the following error in my sbt: module not found: default#ext1_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT